# How to hide the scrollbar in IE10?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, scrollbar

The problem is `scrollbar` always shows up when I move my mouse inside body after I link `bootstrap` style.

At the beginning, the `scrollbar` is hidden. It is working fine. But when I hover the mouse in the `body` area and toggle the mouse wheel, the `scrollbar` shows up. I have set the `overflow` to hidden. But the issue still here.

The code snippet is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        html, body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use vendor specific `-ms-overflow-style`-property to control the scrolling/scrollbar behavior on IE

```
html, body {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

Note that it only applies on elements with `overflow` property set and it only works on Windows 8 and up.

[-ms-overflow-style property on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441298.aspx)

Comment: The issue resolved to apply -ms-overflow-style style. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. Refer to this [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)

```
html::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

This worked fine for me.